# Disable user from typing in text to combo box in visual fox pro

Tags: combobox, visual-foxpro

I'm new to Visual Fox Pro and I have a combo box that I'm populating via an array. What I am trying to do is make it so the user can not type into the combo box and only select from the drop down. I've tried changing the read only property on but this doesn't allow the user to pick any of the drop down fields. Is this possible to do with a combo box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Style property of the combo to 2.